# Joomla 1.5 to 1.6 conversion

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have built a joomla 1.5 template/framework and want to do a conversion to 1.6. My question is whether anyone has done the conversion and do you have any advise on doing the conversion. i.e resources would be helpful. Thanks. C

Answer (score 0):

I haven't converted any of mine yet, but I have looked over the changes and for templates it's rather minor. http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_template_to_Joomla_1.6